# SQL - You have an error in your SQL syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a laravel application which runs this sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `restaurants`
WHERE ABS(-122.1430195 - long) < 0.217125
  AND ABS(37.4418834 - lat) < 0.26937
  AND FIND_IN_SET(egg, allergies) > 0;
)
```

I get this errror:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

I am relatively new with more complex sql, and I have been looking online and I can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put Single quote in 'egg' and avoid "long" for field name because it is keyword of MySQL.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `restaurants` WHERE ABS(-122.1430195 - longitude) < 0.217125   AND ABS(37.4418834 - lat) < 0.26937   AND FIND_IN_SET('egg', allergies) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks this was great, and there isnt a lot of simple documentation on MySQL sets.

Answer (score 4):

You are also using `long` which is reserve word. change your query like this. I am assuming that `egg` and `allergies` are column

```
SELECT *
FROM `restaurants`
WHERE ABS(-122.1430195 - `long`) < 0.217125
  AND ABS(37.4418834 - `lat`) < 0.26937
  AND FIND_IN_SET(egg, allergies);
```

Comment: This was also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

First you have extra `)` after `;`, 
next use quotes around string in `FIND_IN_SET` function like `FIND_IN_SET('egg', 'allergies')`, if they are not table columns

Use this

```
SELECT *
FROM `restaurants`
WHERE ABS(-122.1430195 - long) < 0.217125
  AND ABS(37.4418834 - lat) < 0.26937
  AND FIND_IN_SET('egg', 'allergies') > 0;
```

and if `egg and allergies` are table columns then don't use `quotes`

```
SELECT *
FROM `restaurants`
WHERE ABS(-122.1430195 - long) < 0.217125
    AND ABS(37.4418834 - lat) < 0.26937
    AND FIND_IN_SET(egg, allergies) > 0;
```